# Where are GTK_IM_MODULE and GTK_MODULES set?

Tags: gnome, gtk, eclipse, ibus, input-method

When starting Eclipse for the first time in my Ubuntu 20.04, I got a warning (which actually seem to be 2 warnings)

```
***WARNING: Detected: GTK_IM_MODULE=xim. This input method is unsupported and can cause graphical issues.
***WARNING: Unset GTK_IM_MODULE or set GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus if flicking is experienced. 
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileSnapshot).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

To deal with the `GTK...` warning, I googled a bit.
I found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/262220/137608) that "Gnome made ibus the default input method" (even if the answer is from 2016, figure below suggests it still applies).
But

```
$ env | grep -i gtk
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
```

So I wonder where is `GTK_IM_MODULE` set.
What I tried (with no luck):

```
$ grep -i gtk ~/.bashrc
$ grep -i gtk ~/.profile 
$ grep -i gtk /etc/profile
$ grep -i -nH gtk /etc/profile.d/*
$ grep -i gtk ~/.xprofile 
$ grep -i gtk ~/.xinputrc 
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-im-module
'gtk-im-context-simple'
```

(note that as per `dconf-editor`, the default value is `''`).

I will next try the suggestion in the warning, `Unset GTK_IM_MODULE or set GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus`, but I still have the question:

**Where are `GTK_IM_MODULE` and `GTK_MODULES` set?**

When launching `im-config` I see this

[image]

---

**EDIT**:

Perhaps `~/.xinputrc` is responsible. Its contents:

```
# im-config(8) generated on Tue, 03 Nov 2020 10:36:11 -0300
run_im xim
# im-config signature: 1f92fadecc95eaeaf5534ec0902b5a9b  -
```

**If this is the cause, why would `.xinputrc` contain that?**

---

**EDIT #2**:

I have removed `.xinputrc`, logged out and in again.
Still

```
$ env | grep -i gtk
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
```

So it seems `.xinputrc` was not the culprit.

---

**EDIT #3**:

I executed

```
$ im-config -n ibus
$ im-config -m
default
ibus
ibus

ibus
```

So I made sure `ibus` was current (in the second line of the output, I had `xim` before).
I logged out and in again.
Still

```
$ env | grep -i gtk
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
$ cat .xinputrc 
# im-config(8) generated on Thu, 04 Mar 2021 23:34:26 -0300
run_im ibus
# im-config signature: 3d5777226bbd6243ce412ee4470b8020  -
```

Plus, launching eclipse still gives the same warning (expected, since the environment variables have the same values).
And the ensuing flicker is still present.

As requested in comments

```
$ env | grep -E '_IM|XMOD'
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
XMODIFIERS=@im=none
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

So it seems `.xinputrc` was not the culprit.

---

**EDIT #4**:

After a reboot

```
$ im-config -m
default
ibus
ibus

ibus
$ env | grep -E '_IM|XMOD'
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
$ env | grep -i gtk
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
$ grep -i gtk ~/.profile 
$ grep -i gtk /etc/environment
$ grep -i gtk /etc/environment.d/*
/etc/environment.d/90atk-adaptor.conf:GTK_MODULES=${GTK_MODULES:+$GTK_MODULES:}gail:atk-bridge
```

Plus, eclipse does not show the warning (as expected), and the flicker is gone.

whether `GTK_IM_MODULE` was also set in `/etc/environment.d/90atk-adaptor.conf`, I cannot tell (I would need to try a few things to ascertain that).

Even if not needed:

1. The question about what set `GTK_IM_MODULE` persists.
2. I will try removing `.xinputrc`, rebooting, and checking again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is most likely the cause.

As regards your question why `~/.xinputrc` would contain that, it's a long story. In short it's about various attempts historically to achieve a sensible default configuration. I assume that you installed Ubuntu some years ago, and later upgraded to 20.04.

My advice: Just delete `~/.xinputrc` and reboot. It won't return unless you actively change the input method configuration via e.g. *Language Support*.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio: Really? In that case the only possible explanation is that you created the file yourself. Maybe by selecting "XIM" in _Language Support_. (Unless you kept your `$HOME` from a previous version, of course.)

Comment: Hmmmm... I don't recall doing that, and this installation in fresh new, no previous `$HOME`.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio: The direct way to create such a file is via the command `im-config -n xim`. There is no other way.

Comment: Please see EDIT #4. And I will remove comments to reduce the clutter.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio: Looks like deleting the file plus rebooting fixed it, which is good. As regards how it was created, my initial theory in the answer does apparently not apply to your case. If you find that it was not created by your active measure, it indicates a subtle bug, and in that case I'd appreciate a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that in yet another system with the same issue, executing

```
$ im-config -n ibus
```

and rebooting solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260601/understanding-setting-up-different-input-methods/262220#262220), what you need to do is input

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="ibus"
```

in one of (or all if you are not sure) the following files:

- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.profile
- /etc/profile
- ~/.xprofile
- ~/.config/environment.d/im.conf

based on the information from [here](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Setup_Fcitx_5).

By setting GTK_IM_MODULE to "ibus", the warning message will disappear.

My hypothesis is that the default value "xim" was hard set by some root system files and will constantly set such a value at the boot of the system. By adding the above code, the system will manually set the value to "ibus" during booting, so the warning would not be triggered.